# Creating Hive table for handling fixed length file

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a fixed length file in HDFS on top of which i have to create external  table using regex. 
My file is something like this:

```
12piyush34stack10
13pankaj21abcde41
```

I want it to convert it into a table like:

```
key_column   Value_column
----------   ----------------- 
1234stack    12piyush34stack10
1321stack    13pankaj21abcde41
```

I tried even by substr using insert but i am unable to point to key_columns.
Please help with solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you've used regexp external table but the way cannot workout so as to need also use another substring operation.

If me , I would make a regexp serde table then create two columns(key_column ,  Value_column) and just specify serde option as follows:

> SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
>
> WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
>
> ```
>  "input.regex" ="(\d\d)\w{6}(\d\d).*",
>
>  "output.format.string" = "%1$s%2$sstack %0$s"
> ```
>
> )

The output option will write the space separated data to corresponding columns by order.

Haven't yet test it , mind the back slash may not interpreted right in java.